# Unable to understand complex VLookup Function

Tags: excel, vlookup, benchmarking

I'm having trouble understanding the result of this function `VLOOKUP(A39,'pvtBM ATP'!$A$4:$E$9,5, FALSE)`.

e.g. in the `A39` cell, the value is `'< 8 days'`
As you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

Range From `A4:E9` has the data in the image below:

[image]

So the highlighted value in the above screenshot has the result of the formula which I'm unable to understand.

How is this function providing the highlighted result?

Comment: First place of understanding a function should be the offical [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Answer (score 0):

This is looking up the value of cell A39, from the table in A4:E9, where the value we want is in the 5th column, and the FALSE means we want an exact match of the cell in A39